# Is it bad practice to add interaction to elements not created for interaction?

Tags: html, user-interaction

I wasn't sure how to phrase this so the title is a bit cryptic.

I feel that elements such as `<a>/<button>/etc` were created for user interaction while others such as `<div>/<li>/etc` were created more for structure/organization. Is it bad practice to create user interaction via JS on an `<li>` element rather than using a button or link within the `<li>`?

I feel like it is bad practice, but I don't have a backing for my argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sole reason you may want to prefer 'interactive' elements over non-interactive ones is if you plan for fallback. If you view your site on a Javascript-disabled client, links and buttons will still be clickable, and this lets you provide some fallback. `<li>` tags, and other "non-interactive" elements, will be as inanimate as can be, though.

If this is not a concern, or there is no way anyways that your application can survive without Javascript, then you have no reason to worry.

Comment: I know that they aren't worried about users without JS. Just wasn't sure if there was any specification/etc I was missing. Thanks!